# Width of an Option Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

Good Afternoon,

I have a Select Box, the width of the select box is set to 50px. 
I need to specifiy the width of the option drop box. Right now, my value is so long, that it flows off the screen. I would like to set it to a fixed width like 200px for example. I am trying to get the text to overflow to another line and not be cut off.

I have already tried:

```
option style="width: 200px" 
option width="200"
```

I have tried this as both inline styled and put into my style sheet.

BTW, I am using Chrome and Firefox.

All help is appreciated. ^^

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: I'd suggest using a custom select box plugin, otherwise what you're trying to do simply can't be done due to lack of browser support.

Comment: With a select, you get what you see.

Comment: An alternative is to limit the amount of content that can be in the option's innerText.

Comment: Why is there so much text? What is the function of this particular `select`?

Comment: LOL.... A bigger screen.. I am already at 1080p format... In regards to why so much text, its medical terminology. It has to be so much text.  Can you recommend a good custom select box plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a fixed width for your select box, you can write

```
select{
  width: 200px
}
```

You cannot make text to overflow to another line through standard method. However you might find some plugins online. It is not recommended because of browser compatibility issue.

I found this link which might be helpful [github](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu), [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnagel/GXtpC/embedded/result/)